# Parse specific XML file into object

Tags: c#, xml

I want to deserialize XML file into object, but my XML looks like this

```
<ALLObjects>
<object ID ="1">
    <param1>Clicks</param1>
    <param2>NONE</param2>
    <param3>example</param3>
    <param4>example23</param4>
    <param5>1</param5>
    <param6>1</param6>
</object>

<object ID ="2">
    <param1>Clicks</param1>
    <param2>NONE</param2>
    <param3>Example23</param3>
    <param4>Example 1</param4>
    <param5>10</param5>
    <param6>1</param6>
</object>

 //more objects

</ALLObjects>
```

I have a model that contains all params (including the ID value). I want to load all the object into a list and make some changes and then save it into the same XML file. I know how it works when the XML is int this format

```
<object >
<ID>1</ID>
<param1>Clicks</param1>
<param2>NONE</param2>
<param3>example</param3>
<param4>example23</param4>
<param5>1</param5>
<param6>1</param6>
</object>
```

But I don't want to manually rewrite the whole file to load it into that format. I need a hint what is the best practice for this case. Maybe I need to load it into the JSON and then parse into the object?

@chade_ currently I try to use XmlSerializer, but I've got an error

```
InvalidOperationException: <achievements xmlns=''> was not expected
```

my code: LoadingFromFile

```
  private void LoadData()
    {
        List<AchievementModel> models;

        using (var reader = new StreamReader("test.xml"))
        {
            XmlSerializer deserializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<AchievementModel>),
                new XmlRootAttribute("ALLObjects"));
            models = (List<AchievementModel>)deserializer.Deserialize(reader);
        }
    }


[System.Serializable, XmlRoot("ALLObjects")]
public class AchievementList
{
    public AchievementList() { Items = new List<AchievementModel>(); }
    [XmlElement("object")]
    public List<AchievementModel> Items { get; set; }
}

[System.Serializable, XmlType( "object ")]
public class AchievementModel
{
    public AchievementModel() { }

    [XmlElement("ID")]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("param1")]
    public string Progress { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("param2")]
    public string Reward { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("param3")]
    public string Title { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("param4")]
    public string Description { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("param5")]
    public int param6{ get; set; }
    [XmlElement("param6")]
    public int AchievementAnimalSubtitle { get; set; }
}
}
```

Comment: "...what is the best pratic for this case" what do you use right now?

Comment: @chade_ I update my question

Comment: I don't see `<achievements xmlns=''>` in your example xml. Where is that coming from?

Comment: ught you are sure I check the XMl file and the ALLObjects tag was replace to  achievements .. now its loading correctly but the id of the object is allways 0 (so its not loaded)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to load an attribute value instead of an element from your XML you need to decorate the property in the model class with [`[XmlAttribute]`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlattributeattribute(v=vs.110).aspx):

This model:

```
[System.Serializable, XmlType( "object")]
public class AchievementModel
{
    // serialize attribute on the XmlNode
    [XmlAttribute("ID")]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    // serialize an element value
    [XmlElement("param1")]
    public string Progress { get; set; }
    // other properties omitted
}
```

Will deserialise from this XML:

```
<object ID="2"> <!-- Deserialize ID with XmlAttribute -->
    <param1>Clicks</param1>  <!-- deserialize with XmlElement -->
    <!-- other elements omitted -->
</object>
```